# Can the DNS Server have source IP?

Tags: dns, ip

Short Question :

Since DNS is anycast, is there any way for a DNS Server to know the "first" source DNS Query originated from?

Long Question :
I've developed a custom DynDNS server using PowerDNS, I want to feed it information via web interface by users. I want the web interface to update records for each user "based on IP".

So when the DNS Server gets requests, If it could determine the source IP, it'd be easy to return records associated with that IP.

As long as I tested, the DNS Server can only know the "last" node IP on the DNS chain, not the source. Is there any way?

Regards

Comment: You've described the mechanism, rather than the problem you're trying to solve. Perhaps DNS isn't the best way of doing whatever you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I doubt there's an easy answer to your question, but could you elaborate on exactly what you're trying to do? I googled DynDNS and it hasn't really helped me understand what you're trying to achieve - you want to "feed it information via web interface by users" and you want it to update based on IP? If you could restructure your question, perhaps someone can find a workaround solution that will fit your needs. Additionally, add links to the stuff you're using, which will facilitate understanding a bit more.

Comment: Well, The story is to long to publish here. Put it simple, I have a DNS server, want to know the client IP (where the query was originated), not the recurser asking for the IP. Any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have control of the software performing the lookup? If so, you could include the IP address as part of the request, e.g.

```
23-34-45-56.www.example.com
```

to which your custom-written server replies

```
23-34-45-56.www.example.com 1800 CNAME www-europe.example.com
```

or

```
23-34-45-56.www.example.com  300     A 34.45.56.67
```

etc.

If the client is a web browser, complications arise due to NAT, HTTP proxies, and the inability to query host interface addresses directly from Javascript. However, you might be able to do an AJAX-style lookup to a what's-my-ip service, which understands X-Forwarded-For.

Comment: your idea almost solved my problem, although in a very hard manner :D thanks

Comment: So, the only option is a custom written dns server?

Answer (score 6):

Google and Yahoo! submitted a draft ([draft-vandergaast-edns-client-ip-01](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-vandergaast-edns-client-ip-01)) to the [IETF DNS Extensions Working Group](http://tools.ietf.org/wg/dnsext/) that proposed a new EDNS0 option within DNS requests that recursive servers could use to indicate their own client's IP address to the upstream authoritative server.

The intent was to theoretically optimise the use of Content Delivery Networks by ensuring that the web server addresses returned were based on the end user's IP address, rather than on the address of the end user's DNS server.

The idea was not well received and wasn't accepted by the working group because it intentionally broke the caching layer of the DNS, and the draft has subsequently expired.

**UPDATE** - a variation on this has subsequently been published as [RFC 7871](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7871).

Comment: Thanks but this is not practical at all. e.g OpenDNS decides what to return based on your IP address (or network range). How does it do that? I know on non-recursive requests IP is available , but what how can that be achieved on recursive requests?

Comment: They use custom software to respond based on whatever IP address the client query comes from - that's available whenever the code calls `recv_from`.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm asking. You can't have "client query IP" in DNS, because you might be receiving recursive queries from other servers instead of the original client

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking, then.  Any IP server can determine the IP address of its immediate clients.  So a recursor knows the address of the stub, and an authority knows the address of the recursor.  What an authority doesn't know is the address of the stub.

Comment: and re: your comment, yes, that's what the draft proposed - the recursive cache in this case would have to be "client aware", and re-issue the upstream query if the same request came in from a new client.

Comment: @AbiusX, in normal way, OpenDNS is ´the client´ configured DNS, so it can respond whaterver it wants. autoritative DNS is on diferent situation. excuse my poor english

Comment: Hah, my name's in that RFC, although only as a reviewer. I'm mildly surprised others are aware of it. To the questioner; the only IP address your DNS server sees is that of the last recursive resolver in the chain. There's nothing you can do about this (with DNS as deployed in the world today).

Comment: A DNS server you directly connect to (like OpenDNS) knows your IPAddress. The next servers up the line don't.

Comment: This draft is seeing some activity again. Also, PowerDNS (3.0) now has support for it, including the pipebackend (with a minor bug - i recommend picking up the SVN version for now).

Answer (score 1):

## Long answer to Short Question :

DNS is not anycast.  Some content DNS server owners use anycasting to distribute servers in multiple physical locations around the world, but the DNS/UDP and DNS/TCP protocols themselves are not anycast.  The notion simply doesn't exist at that protocol layer.

## Short answer to Long Question :

No.

## Expansion

As noted, there's nothing in the DNS protocol for this. Moreover, the relationship between front-end and back-end transactions at a [caching resolving proxy DNS server](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-server-roles.html#ResolvingProxy) is not one-to-one.

You'll have to use whatever client differentiation mechanisms exist in the actual service protocol that you're using, instead of putting your client differentiation in the name→IP address lookup mechanism.  Client differentiation for other services doesn't belong in name→IP address lookup, anyway.  Such lookup is common to multiple protocols, for starters.  Use the mechanisms of whatever *actual* service protocol is being used by the clients who are communicating with your servers.

Comment: So how exactly is OpenDNS working? It asks you for your IP and feeds you DNS entries you setup on the website.

Comment: Apples and oranges.  You're messing around with a [content DNS server](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-server-roles.html#Content).  OpenDNS provides a [proxy DNS server](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-server-roles.html#Proxy).